# Parsing JSON Object in JQuery from the Destiny Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

im trying to parse the JSON-Object in Jquery from the Destiny API:

http://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny/Manifest/InventoryItem/712184834/

```
var destiny = "http://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny/Manifest/InventoryItem/712184834/";

$.getJSON(destiny, function (json) {
    var test = json.Response.data.requestedId;
    alert(test);
});
```

But unfortunately its not working ;(

Comment: I would imagine you're being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You need to use a server-side proxy to get information from this API, unless it supports CORS or JSONP. Check the documentation for more info.

Comment: CORS: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.bungie.net`. It will only work from `http://www.bungie.net` origin.

Comment: Define how it 'is not working'

Comment: @: Donald Supertramp: returning no values.

Comment: Rory McCrossan: Ok, that could be a solution

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Rory is correct - we do not support CORS at this time, nor JSONP endpoints.  We encourage you to consider using a server-side proxy - which would also allow you to leverage our mobile Databases for entity definitions, instead of having to query for them on every request.